# Autosubmit for exposed filters and .appendTo

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I want the combobox to my self send exposed filter, I have no problem there it succeeds to do with .change, the problem is that these combobox need them in another div outside the container exposed filter.

This is the code I'm working on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

  $('.form-item-sort-bef-combine,.views-widget-per-page').appendTo('.view-header');

  $('#edit-items-per-page, #edit-sort-bef-combine').change(function() {

    // Submit the form
    //$('.block-views').find('form').submit();
    //$('form#views-exposed-form-vacation-rentals-kiawah-rentals-home').submit();

   $(this).parents('form').submit();

  });
});
```

Everything works until active .AppendTo